# Python generator function confusion

Tags: python, function, generator

Hey so I am working on a program that requires a day/night cycle. Here is the function that I made to get it to start working:

```
def epoch():
    for i in range(0,varb.run_number):
        print("it is now day")
        epoch_state = 1
        yield epoch_state
        time.sleep(varb.day_night_length)
        print("it is now night")
        epoch_state = 0 
        yield epoch_state
        time.sleep(varb.day_night_length)
```

I can find nothing wrong with it, but when I call it I get this:

```
<generator object epoch at 0x01036670>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

P.S. The idea here is to run the cycle while printing out the state and returning the state

P.P.S. anything with varb. is a global with an unimportant numerical value

Comment: That's not an error. You created a generator function...

Comment: OK how could I change my code to do what I need it to?

Comment: Ok I just did list(epoch()) and it worked. What did I do and how do I recreate that if I need to do the same kind of thing again?

Comment: @unknown: `list()` takes an iterator (a generator is a special kind of iterator) and takes all the elements that produces.

Comment: when ever you want it call list(epoch)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the tittle of the question to a tittle that reflects the problem better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error here. The function is working correctly.

You created a *generator function* by using `yield` expressions. You now need to *iterate over your generator*. Until you do, the generator is paused.

You could use `list()` for that:

```
result = list(epoch())
```

or a `for` loop:

```
for result in epoch():
    print(result)
```

Comment: Would `result = list(epoch())` run the loop that is in the function?